# Name of a Sum differentiation Trick

Tags: derivatives, summation, notation

in the [proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299465/proof-variance-of-geometric-distribution), they derive to make the sum prettier. Does this trick have a name and what is its general use case?

---

Comment: I don't know if this ''trick'' (your terminology) has a specific name, but what I can say is that the presentation that is done in the reference you give is not to be copied ''as such"! It is **meaningless to differentiate with respect ot a fixed quantity** ! One should do a computation aside with a true variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim Gowers has an article in his blog called [*Differentiating Power Series*](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2014/02/22/differentiating-power-series/) where he says

> I want to discuss the result that a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n $ is differentiable inside its circle of convergence, and the derivative is given by the obvious formula $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nz^{n-1}$.

This was part of his Analysis IA course in 2014, i.e. a first year Mathematics course at the University of Cambridge.

In effect it allows you to move the differential operator across the summation, thus providing a tool for evaluating some series.  It is particularly useful for generating functions.